# Returning a blob with json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, blob

I'm trying to create a rest service for my android application where an external database returns items to be stored in the applications local database.  I've got everything working except blobs are being returned as null.

this is an example of my jason response.(picture and thumbnail fields are blobs)

```
{"id":"2","user_id":"1","name":"testing","type":"bouldering","picture":null,"lat":"36","long":"81","alt":"41932","accuracy":"53","thumbnail":null}
```

Here is my php script to return the data.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$sql = 'select * from spot_main';
$results =$mysqli->query($sql);

$spots = array();  //array to parse jason from

while($spot = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $spots[] = $spot;                                                           
}

echo json_encode($spots);
?>
```

Anyone know of a solution to this problem?  I know I'm not doing this the most efficient way(better to store images in the filesystem), but I need this to work.

Comment: Please read JSON specification about allowed symbols. http://www.json.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use BLOB with JSON and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855447/how-to-use-blob-with-json-and-php)

Answer (score 31):

Encode the binary data as base64 before you generate the JSON.

```
$obj->picture = base64_encode($binaryData);
```

You can then decode this in your Android application with any base 64 decoder. Since API level 8 there is a built in [util class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html). Otherwise there are plenty of external libs you can use for targetting Android 2.1 or earlier.

Answer (score 13):

**you have to make BLOB to base64_encode**

```
 while($spot = $results->fetch_assoc()){
     $spots[] = $spot;                                                           
    }
```

Then  prepare a foreach loop like this

```
foreach($spots as $key=>$value){
    $newArrData[$key] =  $spots[$key];
    $newArrData[$key]['picture'] = base64_encode($spots[$key]['picture']);
    $newArrData[$key]['thumbnail'] = base64_encode($spots[$key]['thumbnail']);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($newArrData);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `json_encode` works with UTF-8 encoded data only. You can use [json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to detect json_encode error.