# Return eloquent collection as json format

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a RESTful api in Laravel, and I for my index I want to return all the tasks as json.

However, when I use

```
return Response::json(Task::all());
```

I get an error: "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given".

I get the same error when I use:

> return Task::all();

I thought this was supposed to work? What am I doing wrong?

I double-checked to see if Task::all() actually returns anything, and it does. This code does work in another project, although on another server and maybe another php version?

Someone suggested to use toArray(), but I get the same result. Code:

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        $users = User::all();
        $userArray = $users->toArray();
        return Response::json($userArray);
    }

}
```

Comment: where are you calling those ?

Comment: In my index() in my TaskController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response::json function is expecting argument 1 to be an array. From the API:

```
json( string|array $data = array(), integer $status = 200, array $headers = array() )
Return a new JSON response from the application.
```

So you can't just pass through the results of your find, but instead use the toArray() function and pass that through instead:

```
$tasks = Task::all();
Response::json($tasks->toArray());
```

Edit ---

If you're working with a BLOB, then base64_encode it first. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323185/returning-a-blob-with-json) post.

Example:

```
base64_encode($user['image']);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I get the exact same result with this. See post edit.

Comment: Added updated code to question. Note that my Task example was just an example. It's actually about the Users...

Comment: The same error. I just noticed that if I only select username and password it works fine. There is a blob in the user table for an avatar. Could that cause issues?

Comment: Yep, that did it. Note that toArray() is indeed not necessary. It works fine without it.