# array not displaying contents while using a BLOB in database

Tags: php, json, blob

I am using json and php to display the contents of my database, this was working until i implemented a blob value into the database in order to store my pictures and now when i run the page it doesn't display the data, the code i am using is bellow

library2 page

```
 <?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getAllPictures() {
    //  include the login credentials
    include ("loginasdf.php") ; 
    //  connect to the database to get current state
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


    if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "fail";        }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Pictures" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    //  convert to JSON

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    var_dump($rows);
    return json_encode($rows);
   }
```

Display page

```
<?php
 include("library2.php") ;
 $picturetxt = getAllPictures() ;
 $picturejson = json_decode($picturetxt) ;       

    $cl = $picturejson;
    for ($i=0 ; $i<sizeof($cl) ; $i++) {
    echo "<a href=displaycontact2.php?id=" ;
    echo $cl[$i] -> id ;
    echo ">" ;
    echo $cl[$i] -> hname ;
    echo "</a><br/>" ;
    echo "</a><br/>" ;
        echo "ID: ";
            echo $cl[$i] -> ID;
        echo "<br/>";   
        echo "Name: ";
            echo $cl[$i] -> hname;
        echo "<br/>";   
        echo "Image: ";

        ?>
<html>      
    <img src=himage alt="himage"  style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</html>
<?php
   }
   ?>
```

[I get this when i dump $rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti75H.jpg)

Comment: What would you expect to see when you dump $rows? That "blob" is the binary data of the image, exactly what you described it to be.  If you want to transfer it via `json_encode`, you may need to `base64_encode` the blob first, then `base64_decode` it after it's received...

Comment: I don't see where you're actually trying to use the blob data in your code. Nor do I even see a question in your post.

Comment: @cale_b the issue is when i try to display the data the page is blank

Comment: @PatrickQ the issue is when i try to display the data the page is blank

Comment: Well, for starters, you're not generating valid html

Comment: By white page do you mean the server is responding with an blank 500 error?

Comment: If it is a 500 then seeing the php error message would be useful.

Comment: @cale_b my mistake it actually dumps the word NULL

Comment: Troubleshoot: Step through each part of the code.  You know what `var_dump( $rows) ` does - now try `var_dump( $picturetxt );`, then `var_dump($cl);`, etc. until you see where things are broken / not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a blob with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323185/returning-a-blob-with-json)

Comment: @cale_b ok when i dump the $cl now the correct data is displayed, however it isnt actually displaying the data using the "echo $row->id ;"  ect

Comment: @cale_b yeah i was using your answer

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, because I suspect the issue is with your `json_encode` / `json_decode` not handling the binary image data well.

To solve that, you should use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) before assigning to your array, then `base64_decode` after you `json_decode`.

Something like so:

```
$rows = array();
while( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    // base64_encode the image only
    $r['himage'] = base64_encode( 'himage' );
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

Then:

```
$picturejson = json_decode( $picturetxt );       

// may I suggest some simpler code below... don't use for ($i=0...
// $cl = $picturejson;
// for ($i=0 ; $i<sizeof($cl) ; $i++) {

// instead, use foreach( $picturejson....
foreach ( $picturejson AS $row ) {
    // base64_decode the image data
    $row->himage = base64_decode( $row->himage );
    echo "<a href=displaycontact2.php?id=" ;
    // access $row instead of $cl[$i]....
    echo $row->id ;
    // ... etc
    echo "<img src='{$row->himage}'>";
    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: If you are using this answer, can you please comment here, and reference the code that is in the answer.