# Returning SQL Blob from PHP JSON

Tags: php, android, sql, json, blob

I've read many posts regarding PHP/JSON blob processing, but, none seem to provide a clear cut example on how to proceed.  I am trying to communicate with an SQL database on a server.  The table in question has a medium blob field.  I use PHP and JSON to grab the data and display it on an Android phone.  I have no problem with the non-blob data.  I can grab it and display it with no problems.  However, the blob data always returns as "null" via JSON.  I understand that JSON does not directly support binary data, but, my question still remains, how do I access the blob data from the Android system?  The blob data in question is mostly text files (ie. .PDF, .DOC, etc.).  I have no control over the SQL table.  More importantly, how do I get the blob field packaged with the rest of the data so I can process it on the Android platform?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855447/how-to-use-blob-with-json-and-php

Comment: Hey - For some scenarios base64 encoding of binary data solves many problems. It will have a size of 3/2 the original data on the wire which is a problem, but all data is alphanums, why it is easy to transfer. It causes overhead both server and client side though and I dunno about php support, but perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Storing the binary data in a database table might be a bad idea, see this question: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

You can use `base64_encode()` in PHP to encode the binary data.

In PHP it might look something like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
foreach($row as $key => $value){
    $json[$key] = base64_encode($value);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```