# How to get image from MySQL to Android?Using PHP-JSON?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, gridview

How to get image from MySQL DB using PHP & Json and show it in Android Grid view or image view 

How to get the image from DB . I tried to generate JSON data using PHP from MySQl but it showing like this for the image **"Image_Poster":null,** rest of primitive types are am getting the fine output as JSON but Dono how to fix it for image ......

Can any one help for this 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: To add image in json file there are two options. Either give the image link or convert the image data in base64 format and then send it through json.

Comment: How are you storing *said* image in the database?

Comment: Storing Image as BLOB in DB @Darren

Comment: @sam:in DB under what datatype want to store the Image LINK (URL) in String or else any other type

Comment: Simply you can use TEXT type

Comment: [**This might be able to shed some light**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855447/how-to-use-blob-with-json-and-php)

Comment: @sam:no need to use base64 conversion for image link right???

Comment: Yes. Now its simple string. Just add in your JSON

Comment: @sam :got url in JSON output ..Now How to parse it in Android?

Comment: Extract that url string from JSON and call the url to get bitmap image. After getting bitmap image just setBitmap image in the image view.

Comment: @sam:Any reference tutorial

Comment: Definitely. Go through it http://stackoverflow.com/a/5776903/3432566

Comment: @sam:thank you it will work for single image ....what to do for more than one image ??