# Set image type in android

Tags: android, android-image, android-file

I have some code to post an image to my php script that uploads to a database, when it adds to the database the file type is application/oct???? (what is this)

is there anyway of changing this to a jpg file at the android stage?

Below is my code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
             String postURL = "http://10.0.2.2:90/mobileupload3.php";                
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 


         FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);

         MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();  
         reqEntity.addPart("image", bin);
         reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(enteredName));
         reqEntity.addPart("gender", new StringBody(radio));
         reqEntity.addPart("cat", new StringBody(radio2));
         reqEntity.addPart("lat", new StringBody(lat));
         reqEntity.addPart("lon", new StringBody(lon));

         post.setEntity(reqEntity);  
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
         HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
         if (resEntity != null) {    
                   Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
             }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are currently using to upload?

Comment: Problem solved by having this line FileBody bin = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");

Answer (score 0):

application/oct (I assume you mean `application/octet-stream`) is a [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type for a general binary file.

Without more information on your method of upload, I believe that the other part of your question has already been answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544517/uploading-images-to-a-php-server-from-android).