# Android - image upload sending no content

Tags: android, http-post

I've been looking into this for the last day or two and can not seem to find a solution to my issue. I am trying to post an image to a server using httppost.
I have tried two ways of doing this and both complete the post but with no content i.e. the content length is 0.
The first is as follows:

```
String url = "MYURL";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     try {
             httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(90000)); // 90 second
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
             File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00004.jpg");
             FileEntity entity;
             entity = new FileEntity(file,"binary/octet-stream");
             entity.setChunked(true);
             post.setEntity(entity);
             post.addHeader("Header", "UniqueName");
             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
             if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                     Log.e("Here","--------Error--------Response Status line code:"+response.getStatusLine());
             }else {
                     // Here every thing is fine.
             }

             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             if (resEntity == null) {
                 Log.e("Here","---------Error No Response!!-----");
             }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
             Log.e("Here","---------Error-----"+ex.getMessage());
             ex.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
               httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     }
```

and the second is:

```
String url = "MYURL";
        //File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00004.jpg");
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true);
            // Send in multiple parts if needed
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d("finishing", "The try catch function");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // show error
        }*/
```

As you can see I have hardcoded a path to a specific image, this is to be dynamic when I get it up and running. 
Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong? Am I leaving out something? I know I use setChunked and setContenttype - is there a setContent option?
Any help would be grately appreciated.

Thanks,
jr83.

Answer (score 1):

You can use upload your image by sending multipart messages; you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544517/uploading-images-to-a-php-server-from-android) discussion useful.