# Android Image Uploading

Tags: android

I am new to android.Now am going to upload an image to php server.I have searched so many links but I didn't get the proper solution from those.So please anybody help me for this.
Requirement is:
1.I want to upload a image from the android sd card to php server.
2.Using multipart entity.

So please give me some running code.Thank you for any answer.

Comment: do you have webservice using which you can post the image data?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037717/upload-an-image-and-audio-in-one-request-in-android/7038888#7038888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see basically you need to have the PHP based webservice that allow you to upload your photo and then you can code for image upload in JAVA using andoid.

[Uploading images to a PHP server from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544517/uploading-images-to-a-php-server-from-android) is the top link for all your questions.

also http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/ is the explanation that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation.. You can upvote for those question that you feel helpfull or should be upvoted... also try to accept answer.